# DeleteFile() or unlink() calls succeed but doesn't remove file

Tags: c, windows, winapi, win32-process

I am facing this strange problem.
To delete a file [unlink()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c3tczd6.aspx) API is called in my code. This call removes the file and succeeds on non-windows platforms. On windows it succeeds (returns 0) but doesn't remove the file.

To experiment I added a loop to call same API repeatedly. In second iteration I got an Permission denied error, Error code =13. Though read/write attributes are set on file and program has full permission to access the file.

I then called [DeleteFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of unlink() API. To my surprise I see the same result,call succeeded i.e. returned 1 but file is not removed physically.

I checked through unlocker utility, no other program is accessing the file except the program which is trying to remove this file.

Does anyone has idea what else could be wrong ?

**Edit1:**
Just to ensure file was not opened at the time of removing it. I saved the handle when file was created and tried to close before removing the file but I got error "'UNOPENED' (Errcode: 9 - Bad file descriptor)". Thus I conclude the file was not open at the time of removing it.

**Edit2**
As requested, here is the simplified version of code used to create and remove the file.

```
// Code to create the file
int create_file(const char* path)
{
  HANDLE osfh;                            /* OS handle of opened file */
  DWORD fileaccess;                       /* OS file access (requested) */
  DWORD fileshare;                        /* OS file sharing mode */
  DWORD filecreate;                       /* OS method of opening/creating */
  DWORD fileattrib;                       /* OS file attribute flags */
  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES SecurityAttributes;


  SecurityAttributes.nLength= sizeof(SecurityAttributes);
  SecurityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor= NULL;
  SecurityAttributes.bInheritHandle= !(oflag & _O_NOINHERIT);



 fileaccess= GENERIC_WRITE;
 fileshare= FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE;
 filecreate= CREATE_NEW; 


 if ((osfh= CreateFile(path, fileaccess, fileshare, &SecurityAttributes, 
 filecreate, fileattrib, NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
 {
   // error handling
 }

}

//Code to delete the file - 
int remove_file (const char* name)
{
  if ((err = unlink(name)) == -1)
  { //Error handling }
}
```

**Edit3**
As pointed by *Joachim Pileborg*  and  *icabod*, that `DeleteFile()` does not remove file if it is still open.  As suggested by *Remy Lebeau*, to use process explorer. I found that one handle to file was indeed open when I closed that from process explorer file deleted like a charm :)

I had also mentioned in the **Edit1** when I tried to close the file I got an error. It happened because the file descriptor I get from `createfile()` is not the actual handle returned by CreateFile() API instead a logical mapped handle due to underlying code complexities to support other non-windows platforms. Anyways, now I understood the root cause of problem but I was expecting if a file with open handle is passed to `DeleteFile()` API then it should fail in first attempt rather succeed and wait for open handles to close.

Comment: You say "no other program is accessing the file except the program which is trying to remove this file". Does that mean you have the file opened in your program (with e.g. `open`, `fopen` or `CreateFile`)? Then no it will not be removed from the disk as your program still has it open. If you close the file first and *then* remove it, it should work.

Comment: I find it weird if people feel question not worth asking say that along with down vote. What's wrong with the question ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg if the file is still open, shouldn't `DeleteFile` return false ?

Comment: @Rahul post some code. BTW `_unlink` doesn't do much more than calling `DeleteFile` so it's actually normal that if `_unlink` fails, `DeleteFile` fails too. And what does `GetLastError()` return when `DeleteFile` has failed?

Comment: @MichaelWalz It depends on if the `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` flag has been set or not I guess (I'm not that home with the Windows API). But now I agree that it's really time to see a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MichaelWalz Ah!  I debugged and further realized that '_unlink' calls 'DeleteFile'

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg - Thank you. I've provided the sample code with which I face the problem. Yes, FILE_SHARE_DELETE is set while creating the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you call your `Createfile` function, then later call your `remove_file` function... you still have a handle open to the file. The WinAPI function `CreateFile`, if it succeeds, keeps a handle open on the file. In your provided code, you don't close that handle.

From the documentation on [DeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The DeleteFile function marks a file for deletion on close. Therefore, the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is closed. Subsequent calls to CreateFile to open the file fail with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

My guess is that you still have a handle open, and when you close that handle the file will be deleted.

However, your sample code is incomplete, so it is difficult to tell.

Comment: You can use a tool like SysInternals Process Explorer to find out who has an open handle to the file being deleted.

Comment: Yes, PE is very useful for that. I would note tho' that you shouldn't use it to force a handle closed - as [Raymond Chen points out](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.windowsconfidential.aspx), it could be _very bad_. Better to ensure you close all your own handles, and if you're worried about others accessing the file, don't open it with `SHARED` access.